# How to say one observation sparked the remembrance of a concept

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

When I looked at two of my friends fighting, it made me remember of a scene in a book I read. Is there any word to say "remember" but in the sense that you time traveled to a particular experience or story that was originally sparked off by an observation you had in the present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could say the observation **triggered** a memory. Or if you want the recollection to seem more vivid, you could say the observation **pulled** you back to the scene you remembered.

Answer (score 1):

You could say than an observation ***prompted*** you to remember something.

Answer (score 1):

The observation brought back memories.

Comment: It evoked memories

Answer (score 0):

The experience you describe could well be termed [déjà vu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9j%C3%A0_vu).